# update object1 field based on object2 records

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I have written this code its working but I have to write this same code in batch apex. How to do?
thanks in advance.

```
trigger rrr on Demand__c (before insert) {
    for(demand__c d:trigger.new){
         system.debug(d.rrd_number__c);
        list<idc_demand__c> b=[select id,rrd_number__c from idc_demand__c where rrd_number__C=:d.rrd_number__c];
    system.debug(b);
        if(b.size()==0){
          system.debug('no'); 
            d.idc_chek__c='No';
        }else{
            system.debug('yes');
            d.idc_chek__c='Yes';
        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Hi Ravi, can you share what you have tried so far and where you are stuck? The [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm) has some examples of how to do this

Comment: You should also refactor your trigger to move the idc_demand__c query outside the loop to avoid hitting the SOQL governor limit when many Demand__c objects are inserted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is sample code to update object record based on other objects:

```
    global class UpdateContactBasedOnAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
    {

       global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC)
       {
          // Fetch Accounts
          return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT id FROM Account');
       }

       global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope){
         List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>)scope;

         List<Contact> contactList = [SELECT id from Contact where AccountId in :accountList];

         /**
         // Do whatever you want with contacts list based on Account id.
         **/

         update contactList;
        }

       global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
       {
         // will be called in end when batch finish.
       }
    }
```

Read some information about batch apex to understand clearly: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_batch_interface.htm

If you are trying to run batch from trigger then it doesn't come in good practice to execute batch from trigger.

Answer (score 2):

As others have stated, your code is querying in a for loop, so clean that up and see if that solves your need for a batch job.  My guess is you're getting a too many query limit exception thrown, hence why you're looking at a batch job.

Ideally you should move the logic out of the trigger into a new Apex class, but in the mean time, I've taken your trigger code and hopefully made it more performant:

```
trigger rrr on Demand__c (before insert) {

    //Not sure what type of field rrd_number__c is, so might have to change these Maps and Sets.
    Set<String> rrdNumbers = new Set<String>();
    for(Demand__c d : (List<Demand__c>)trigger.new) {
        rrdNumbers.add(d.rrd_number__c);
    }

    Set<String> rrdNumbersInIDCDemand = new Set<String>();
    for(Idc_Demand__c idc : 
        [Select 
            Rrd_number__c 
         From 
            Idc_demand__c 
         Where 
            Rrd_Number__c in :rrdNumbers]){
        //If the RRD number is found in this set, then the "Idc Chek" flag is to be true
        rrdNumbersInIDCDemand.add(idc.Rrd_Number__c);
    }

    for(Demand__c d : (List<Demand__c>)trigger.new) {
        //Sets the check__c field to yes or no 
        //depending on whether rrd_number__c was found in Idc_demand
        //Also, consider making this a checkbox field rather than a text field.
        d.idc_chek__c = rrdNumbersInIDCDemand.contains(d.rrd_number__c) ? 'yes' : 'no';
    }
}
```

If you still need to write a batch job, it might look similar to this:

```
global class UpdateContactBasedOnAccount implements Database.Batchable<Demand__c>{

    global List<Demand__c> start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
        //Not sure what filter criteria you want for this query if any...
        return [Select Rrd_Number__c From Demand__c];
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Demand__c> scope){
        Map<String, Integer> rrdNumberToCount = new Map<String, Integer>();
        for(Demand__c d : scope) {
            rrdNumberToCount.put(d.rrd_number__c, 0);
        }

        Set<String> rrdNumbersInIDCDemand = new Set<String>();
        for(Idc_Demand__c idc : 
         [Select 
             Rrd_number__c 
          From 
             Idc_demand__c 
          Where 
             Rrd_Number__c in :rrdNumbers]){
            //If the RRD number is found in this set, then the "Idc Chek" flag is to be true
            rrdNumbersInIDCDemand.add(idc.Rrd_Number__c);
        }

        for(Demand__c d : scope) {
            //Sets the check__c field to yes or no 
            //depending on whether rrd_number__c was found in Idc_demand
            //Also, consider making this a checkbox field rather than a text field.
            d.idc_chek__c = rrdNumbersInIDCDemand.contains(d.rrd_number__c) ? 'yes' : 'no';
        }

        //In a before insert, you dont need to update the list of demand__c objects, but
        //in this batch job you will.
        update scope;
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        // will be called in end when batch finish.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need to remember is that you should take the SOQL out of the for loop. Do the SOQL first and then handle the query result. Before you do the SOQL, you may need to do a simple loop to gather the information needed for the SOQL. Your code should be like:

```
trigger rrr on Demand__c (before insert) {

    // Suppose rrd_number__c is of type String
    Map<String, Integer> rrdNumberToCount = new Map<String, Integer>();
    for(Demand__c d : trigger.new) {
        rrdNumberToCount.put(d.rrd_number__c, 0);
    }

    for (AggregateResult ar : [select rrd_number__c, count(Id) from idc_demand__c where rrd_number__c in :rrdNumberToCount.keySet() group by rrd_number__c])  {
        String rrdNumber = (String) ar.get('rrd_number__c');
        String count = (Integer) ar.get('expr0');
        rrdNumberToCount.put(rrdNumber, count);
    }

    for(Demand__c d : trigger.new) {
        Integer size = rrdNumberToCount.get(d.rrd_number__c);
        if(size == 0){
            system.debug('no'); 
            d.idc_chek__c='No';
        } else{
            system.debug('yes');
            d.idc_chek__c='Yes';
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP has added the tags **scheduled-apex** and  **schedulebatch** so it appears they are looking for a solution using Batch Apex rather than changing the trigger code to handle batches.

Comment: But your code is correct and @ravi should be using that pattern in their trigger.

Comment: I downvoted this answer because the code is wrong - it is applying the same rrd_number__c  count based decision to all Demand__c objects. And it is perfectly possible that ravi also needs batch-oriented code as well to e.g. update existing data.

Comment: You are right. The code was originally focused on moving the idc_demand__c query outside the loop. I just updated my code.

Comment: Think an aggregate result query is a lot of overkill in this case.  Why not simply add the rrd numbers found in IDC Demand to a set, then check to see if the Demand__c rrd number is found in that set?  (See my example).

Comment: @user6941 Thanks for improving the code though it is probably still broken when d.rrd_number__c is null because that leaves "size" null and so "size == 0" is false. I suggest this shows why tests are so important: even familiar patterns can involve edge cases best sorted out with tests.

Comment: @KeithC I have removed "if (d.rrd_number__c != null) {" in the section of populating the map so that it is taking care of the null rrd_number__c now.

Comment: @user6941 Yeah its probably OK now. I'd really like to just change the -1 to 0 but the platform forces me to go to +1 so there you go.